# JS RPS Best-Of-5 function has to run an additional time to give winner result

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm very new to JS, day 7 of learning/coding for an hour or 2 per day. I am making a JS RPS game, everything works well, except when I'm trying to run a function for a Best of 5 game. it counts everything properly, but, when it gets to 5, I have to run the function an additional time to get the Winner result.

I understand why it's doing this, because before the function runs the value is < 5. I'm just not sure how to fix it, I've searched around a lot, but probably am not using the proper search terms.

Code:

```
const playRound = function (cpuChoice, playerChoice) {
  if (playerChoice === cpuChoice) {
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerChoice} and CPU chose ${cpuChoice}, It's a Tie`);
    result('Tie!', 'yellow');
  } else if ((playerChoice === 'rock' && cpuChoice === 'scissors') || (playerChoice === 'paper' && cpuChoice === 'rock') || (playerChoice === 'scissors' && cpuChoice === 'paper')) {
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerChoice} and CPU chose ${cpuChoice}, You Win`);
    result('You Win!', 'green');
    playerScore++;
    document.querySelector('.player-score').textContent = playerScore;
  } else {
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerChoice} and CPU chose ${cpuChoice}, You Lose`);
    result('You Lose', 'red');
    cpuScore++;
    document.querySelector('.cpu-score').textContent = cpuScore;
  }
};

const playGame = function (playerScore, cpuScore) {
  if (playerScore === 5) {
    console.log(`You Won The Best Of 5, ${playerScore} to ${cpuScore}.`);
  } else if (cpuScore === 5) {
    console.log(`You Lost The Best Of 5, ${playerScore} to ${cpuScore}.`);
  } else if (playerScore < 5 && cpuScore < 5) {
    playRound(cpuChoice, playerChoice);
    console.log('next round');
  }
};
```

Comment: put the win check after playRound

Answer (score 0):

Change your `playGame` to so that the winning check is made after each game.

```
const playGame = function (playerScore, cpuScore) {
  if (playerScore < 5 && cpuScore < 5) {
    playRound(cpuChoice, playerChoice);
    console.log('next round');
  }

  if (playerScore === 5) {
    console.log(`You Won The Best Of 5, ${playerScore} to ${cpuScore}.`);
  } else if (cpuScore === 5) {
    console.log(`You Lost The Best Of 5, ${playerScore} to ${cpuScore}.`);
  }
};
```

Comment: This had the same issue. but, I created a function checkWinner, with the winner if statement, and ran checkWinner() after playGame() and it seems to be working now. not sure if this is ideal, but it's working now.